# Как установить драйвер?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Я начал изучать Selenium. Нашел один проект в инете, где уже был установлен Framework для пользования Selenium Webdriver. У меня такая проблема, что я не понимаю где (или как) я должен подключить драйвер (который я скачиваю с инета). Код не прикрепляю, так как его там слишком много и я не знаю что именно нужно показать. Может кто-то поймет о чем я, и поможет. Буду рад каждому ответу!

Comment: начните поиски со строчек **from selenium import webdriver** и **browser = webdriver.Firefox()** (или webdriver.Chrome()) и спрашивайте

Comment: @Jack_oS, спасибо, но уже как-то само решилось:)